# ASP.Net MVC post value in a combo box

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

We have a list of items on a ASP.Net MVC page, each row in the list has a combo box.

When the user selects a value in the combobox, we would like the form to be submitted. We also need to be able to read which line the user was on and which value was selected.

We have given each combobox a name that links it to the row on which it was on.

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do this with javascript, something like (jQuery)

```
$(".comboboxClass").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("form").submit(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but how do I connect this script to the combobox?

Comment: This is a selector that will attach it to the combo boxes with the class "comboboxClass". Put this in a script area on the page with the appropriate jQuery script reference and you should be done.

Comment: Download the jQuery javascript file from http://jquery.com/ also take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery